# Relation between 2 different homology and cohomology pairings

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Consider $X$ $n-$dimensional smooth compact oriented manifold. Denote $H^i(X,\Omega)$ as the cohomology of smooth differential form, $H_i(X)$ as the $i-$th cycles and $C_i(X)$ as the singular chains and $Z^i(X)$ as the $i-$the cocycles of differential forms.

There are 2 different pairings.

$C_i(X)\times Z^i(X)\to R$ by $\int_c\omega$ where $c\in C_i(X),\omega\in Z^i(X)$. This obviously descends to $H_i(X)\times H^i(X,\Omega)\to R$ by Stokes Thm. Clearly I have embedding $H_i(X)\to (H^i(X,\Omega))^\star$ by shrinking the target cycle I need.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is this isomorphism?

The other one is $C^i(X)\times C^{n-i}(X)\to R$ by $\int_X \omega_i\wedge\omega_{n-i}$ with $\omega_k\in C^k(X)$. Clearly this also descends to $H^i(X)\times H^{n-i}(X,\Omega)\to R$. This pairing is non degenerate.

$\textbf{Q:}$ What is the relationship between the 2 pairings? By poincare duality, I have $H_i(X)\cong H^{n-i}(X)$. So second pairing can be replaced by $H_i(X)\times H^i(X,\Omega)\to R$. Should I say if $\omega_2\in H^{n-i}(X,\Omega)$ is identified with a cycle $c\in H_i(X)$, given $\omega_1\in H^i(X)$, I consider $\int_c\omega_1=\int_X\omega_1\wedge\omega_2$? Is this even correct?

Comment: May be you want to say "Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold".. Is your $R$ the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: This is, more or less, the definition of the Poincare dual.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval I thought poincare duality is obtained by intersection with top form rather than by this identification.

Comment: Do you see that you are writing $M$ in the first place and then $X$ there after... The real numbers are related by $\mathbb{R}$..

Comment: Are you considering real homology/cohomology or integral homology/cohomology?

Comment: @TedShifrin I am considering real homology by Kunneth formula.

Comment: So then it's just the deRham isomorphism (giving the isomorphism between singular real cohomology and deRham cohomology) and Poincaré duality.

Comment: @TedShifrin Then you mean I should get a commutative diagram to establish the equality $\int_c\omega_1=\int_X\omega_1\wedge\omega_2$?

Comment: I'm saying that's the definition of Poincaré duality, the cohomology class $[\omega_2]$ being the Poincaré dual of the cycle $c$.